# How to push to netlify in production mode [Nuxt JS]

Tags: vue.js, push, nuxt.js, netlify

I have my app created with nuxt js. I just want to push my app on Netlify.

So firstly i configure my deploy settings :

> Repository on git
>
> Base directory : Not set
>
> Build command npm run build && npm run start
>
> Publish directory .nuxt/dist

My app is build correctly but npm run start just launch on localhost:3000

I decided to modify config Host, I don't know if it's the best solution ?

```
{
  "name": "app-nuxt",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "My remarkable Nuxt.js project",
  "author": "wyllisMonteiro",
  "private": true,
  "config": {
    "nuxt": {
      "host": "https://mywebsite.com"
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "HOST=localhost PORT=3000 nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.3.6",
    "cookieparser": "^0.1.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.0",
    "nuxt": "^2.4.0",
    "vee-validate": "^2.2.0",
    "vuelidate": "^0.7.4",
    "vuetify": "^1.5.5",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.0-beta.27",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "^24.1.0",
    "coffee-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "coffeescript": "^2.4.0",
    "jest": "^24.1.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.9",
    "pug": "^2.0.3",
    "pug-plain-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "stylus": "^0.54.5",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.2",
    "vue-jest": "^3.0.3"
  }
}
```

I want to launch in localhost:3000 by executing npm run dev
AND https://mywebsite.com by executing npm run start

Can you tell me if there is some modifications in my package.json or in my deploy settings on Netlify

Comment: My understanding is that you can only host a statically generated site on Netlify at this stage. As you are trying npm run start it would seem you have a Universal app. See [docs](https://nuxtjs.org/faq/netlify-deployment/). If you want a free hosting option, you might want to consider [Heroku](https://nuxtjs.org/faq/heroku-deployment) instead.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that stumbles across this in the future, the problem you're experiencing is due to a misunderstanding with what services Netlify offers.

Specifically, they are primarily a static site host, which means they will host your built files, and serve them for you.  They will not run your server, which means `nuxt start` will **not** run.

Instead, you should be using `nuxt generate` to generate the static files of your app, and telling Netlify where the output folder is.

For example, the "build settings" on Netlify:

```
Repository         github.com/example/example
Base directory     Not set
Build command      npm run generate
Publish directory  dist
```

This will properly deploy a Nuxt app, assuming you haven't changed the default build folder.  For clarification, the `.nuxt` folder contains both client and server files, and can only be used when running your own Nuxt server on an instance of some kind.

Answer (score 0):

As it looks you need to tweak your deployment command. Go to Netlify and try changing it to `npm install; npm run build`. This should resolve the problem.

Comment: You don't need to npm install on netlify;  it happens automatically for you.  Answers like "it doesn't work" aren't helpful in us debugging further, so please provide details such as a link to your deploy logs if you want further debugging help.